# Multiple join using Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am looking at moving a website from ASP.NET Web Pages to MVC. I need to understand how i do mutliple joins using entity framework.

I currently have 3 database tables with a model for each.

- Property
- Rooms
- RoomType

The code below gets all the info from the rooms table for each property, but it just gives me a `RoomTypeID` from the `Rooms` table. What I need is to get the `RoomType` from the `RoomType` table using that ID.

```
@model manage.stayinflorida.co.uk.DataModels.Property_Info

    @foreach (var item in Model.RoomInfoes)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RoomTypeID)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RoomDescription)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
```

Comment: Look for some join examples for entity framework.  Also, look at navigation properties...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MVC 5 Multiple Models in a Single View](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23536299/mvc-5-multiple-models-in-a-single-view)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually with Entity Framework, you get a Navigation Property on your entities if they have a foreign key relation.

This means you can access the property from the related type as well.

If your `RoomInfos` class has a property called `RoomType` of type `RoomType` (which is linked on the RoomTypeID) you can therefore access this in your model.

An example is shown below - the example is assuming you have a property on 'RoomType' called 'Name'.

```
@model manage.stayinflorida.co.uk.DataModels.Property_Info

@foreach (var item in Model.RoomInfoes)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RoomType.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RoomDescription)
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

See [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/jj713564.aspx) for additional information about Navigation Properties.

Comment: This is exactly what i was after, thanks Rob. The link about Navigation Properties is also really useful.