# Can we have Multiple partial views with different models inside a single view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, partial-views, razor-2

Hi everyone am developing an application using ASP.NET MVC 5 and I want to display different models using partial views inside a single view is that possible or I have to make a model for the parent view that includes all the models of the partials ???

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple models in a view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764011/multiple-models-in-a-view)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understood you want use more than one model per view and this is not possible. You need a object with others objects inside. (like you said a model to the parent view that includes all models of the partials).

Your post maybe duplicated for this:
[MVC 5 Multiple Models in a Single View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23536299/mvc-5-multiple-models-in-a-single-view)

Comment: Thank you Ciro, but is this the only solution ??

Comment: If you want you can use a dynamic object as model but i prefer a ViewModel like solution. saddly we cant use more than one model per view in razor.

Comment: Thank you Ciro , so I will use a parent ViewModel.